# Search loop in json array decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, search

I'm newbie in json data. My question is how to make a loop to search a value into the json array? My code is in PHP. For example, I want to find the value 59.
Here is my json and I'm already using json_decode:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 58
    [1] => Dent_a
    [2] => 34
)
Array
(
    [0] => 59
    [1] => Dent_b
    [2] => 33
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

My code returns blank.

```
$data= json_decode(json_encode($ages), true); 
for ($i=2; $i<(count($data)+2); $i++){ 
    if($data[$i]== '59' ){
        print_r("found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which language is this? Also, what is `Dent_A` and `Dent_B`? Is your data spread over four separate arrays? Please post your actual working code.

Comment: @AaditMShah It's PHP.  It is student and student b, 58 and 59 are the IDs, and 34 and 33 are the grades. I'm trying to search by ID.